# Unable to download/stream video file on IOS devices using WCF services

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, video, stream

I was implementing a simple WCF service function for downloading files (mostly  image and video) from the server, which is as follows

```
 public Stream downloadFile(String filePath)
    {
        FileStream file = null;
        try
        {

            String appPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files");
            String filocation = Path.Combine(appPath, @filePath);
            file = File.OpenRead(filocation);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Status", "200");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control ", "private");
                }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IOException : {0}", e);
        }

        return file;

    }
```

The webhttpBinding used in web.config for the service is as follows

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WebConfiguration" 
           maxBufferSize="65536" 
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"
           transferMode="Streamed">
  </binding>
```

and also

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="67108864"/>
```

**The service function works fine on pc and all Android devices for all files but the video isn't playing/downloading using this function on IOS devices.**

I have implemented Http Range header to check if that was an issue but it didn't work out. I don't know what is the issue with the IOS device, not streaming/downloading the video file.

Any solution to this issue? Thanks.